# Windows Azure, OpenID Back Button Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, openid

I am working on a website that uses OpenID for authentication.  Once linked a user need only click on the "Log In" button and they are allowed into the site.  However, after being allowed into the site, if the user clicks the back button, they are given the following error:

> An error occurred while processing your request.
>
> HTTP Error Code:    403
> Message:    ACS30000: There was an error processing an OpenID sign-in response.
> Inner Message:  ACS30001: Unable to verify the OpenID response signature.
> Inner Message:  ACS50006: Signature verification failed.
> Trace ID:   13092d63-ea7a-4ed2-9321-5e9054321322
> Timestamp:  2012-06-29 19:48:06Z

Please help me identify a cause and maybe a way to fix it.

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Comment: Hi. You apparently work with ACS. Is the OpenID something that you've implemented or is it some "open" OpenID provider. My idea is, that if it a "open" - could you give me it's address so I could setup and test. It hard to say what the issue is without tracing the actual messages with Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will always happen. But one workaround in my mind is to use JavaScript’s window.history to remove the last browser history entry on the redirected page. This also helps to “hide” the authentication details.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.